Why does my image disappear when I apply the width attribute?
I'm trying to create an app with react native,
this is the code atm:
import { View, Text, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <View>
        <Image source={require('./../assets/images/login.jpg')}
            style={{
              width: '100%',      
            }}
        />
    </View>
  )
}


The problem is when I apply the width attribute, because my image just disappear.
If I don't use that attribute it's all good, I can use height and it's working properly, but as soon as I use width I just see a white screen. I tried different images, different %, but same result.
PS:This error is only when I use %, if I use px is working.
Can you explain to me why this is happening?
Thank you.
I wanted the image to cover the entire width of the background.

If you want the image to cover the entire width of the background, you can use flex container for your background views and set the image width to 100% to take up the whole container - Try this:
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';

export default function Login() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Image 
        source={require('./../assets/images/login.jpg')}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: undefined, aspectRatio: 1 }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

You have to define in the view when you use % but px you don't need to define as it was set in the React Native system
